# Create setter for a style property

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

I want to make a setter for the fontSize property of my WrappedLabel class because I need to do some additional stuff when someone changes it.
So when someone uses my class like this:

```
<comp:WrappedLabel fontSize="10"/>
```

I want to know.

I tried to override setStyle but looks like it doesn't get called when fontSize is initialized in mxml.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually easier to accomplish then you might think, but it involves metadata. All you need to do is add a `Style` metadata declaration to your class definition, like so:

```
[Style(name="fontSize", type="Number", inherit="no")]
public class WrappedLabel {
    ...
}
```

If you want more information on the parameters of the metadata, [read the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf680e1-7ffe.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a1a).